# Wildcards in typeid

Tags: c++, typeid

There is a section of code in a library I use that looks like this:

```
...
     if ( ptype == typeid( Vector< T, 4 > ) )
       {
       This->SetNumberOfComponents(4);
       }
     else if ( ptype == typeid( Vector< T, 5 > ) )
       {
       This->SetNumberOfComponents(5);
       }
...
```

If there any way to make this more generic by doing something like

```
 if ( ptype == typeid( Vector< T, ANYTHING > ) )
       {
       This->SetNumberOfComponents(THE_SECOND_TEMPLATE_PARAM);
       }
```

?

Thanks,

David

Comment: Can you template on the exact Vector type rather than store a typeid object?  That's more conventional and gives this a trivial solution.

Comment: If I change the interface to this function it will be a giant task to find everywhere in the library it is called and change it. Changing the internals of the function only is all I can afford to do at the moment.

Comment: Roger, I want to accept your answer of "just don't use typeid" - can you create an "answer" rather than a "comment" so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We took Roger Pate's suggestion of removing the use of typeid by restructuring a little bit (It was the first comment, so I couldn't mark it as the answer). Thanks for all of the great ideas and discussion!

Answer (score 3):

Do you have access to the Vector class?

If so, you can add a static field inside the Vector class which simply echoes back the second template parameter:

```
template<class T, int SIZE>
class Vector
{
   // ...
   public:
      static const int NUM_COMPONENTS = SIZE;
   // ...
};
```

Comment: I have access to the vector class, but I don't have the instance of the class in this function, I only the have the 'ptype' variable.

Answer (score 2):

An optimising compiler will inline this recursive definition into the equivalent of your if ladder:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct TestType {
    static void Test ( const std::type_info& ptype ) {
        if ( ptype == typeid ( Vector< T, N > ) )
            This->SetNumberOfComponents ( N );
        else
            TestType < T, N - 1 >::Test ( ptype );
    }
};

// need to have a base case which doesn't recurse
template<typename T>
struct TestType<T, 0> {
    static void Test ( const std::type_info& ptype ) {}
};

const size_t MAX_DIMENSIONS ( 12 );

template<typename T>
void SetNumberOfComponents ( VectorBase<T>* p )
{
    const std::type_info& ptype ( typeid ( *p ) );

    TestType<T, MAX_DIMENSIONS>::Test ( ptype );
}
```

Comment: This is much better than it is currently, (no code duplication), but my motivation was to allow arbitrarily long vectors (you have chosen 12, the library has chosen 7, but what if you want a 128 length vector? Or 1000? You wouldn't want to have to check against all of these 1000 types!

Comment: If you have 1000 different types, and the only information you have to differentiate between them is the identity of ptype, then you are going to have to check them all. It would be better to have the Vector expose its size instead; but if you're limited to only changing the client code you will to get ugly and not scale that well ( possibly O(lnN) if you sort the names of the types, or less with a hashmap, but that's still ugly ).

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do some some macro hacking, so you wouldn't have to write too much repeated code.

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
    void SetNumberOfComponents(int n) { std::cout << n << '\n'; }
};

template <class T, int N>
struct Vector{};

typedef int T;

void foobar(const std::type_info& ptype)
{
    #define SUPPORTED_VECTOR_TYPES 20
    #define BRANCH(z, n, text) else if (ptype == typeid(Vector<T, n>)) {This->SetNumberOfComponents(n);}
    X x;
    X* This = &x;
    if (0); BOOST_PP_REPEAT(SUPPORTED_VECTOR_TYPES, BRANCH, UNUSED)
    #undef SUPPORTED_VECTOR_TYPES
    #undef BRANCH
}

int main()
{
    foobar(typeid(Vector<int, 10>));
}
```

Comment: UncleBens, my motivation (should have mentioned this originally, sorry) was actually to not restrict the length of the vector. That is, if a user wants to use a length 1000 vector, it seems crazy to compare it to every type <T, 1>, <T, 2> ... <T, 1000> until it matches. Is there any way to do this without going through all the types?

Comment: I think that's what you get when you try to use **run-time** type information instead of compile time things. - As a very non-portable solution, you might check what the name string contains.